# Select menu, match json list with singular value

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, input, angular-ngmodel

I have a JSON file of the US states, name and 2-letter code bound to a menu via a factory/controller variable of `usStates`

```
[
 {"name":"Alabama","code":"AL"},
 {"name":"Alaska","code":"AK"}, ...]
```

So, I use this for my menu: `ng-options="s.code for s in id.usStates"`

Works fine, displays my states.

The back-end dev gave me the JSON I am supposed to link with, and he has this value as such:

```
"subCity": "",
"cityTown": "Selma",
"stateProvince": "AL",
"postalCode": "000000",
"zip4": "",
"countryCode": "US"
```

So I tried adding this item as my ng-model,

```
<select ng-model="id.partner.partnerAddressInfo.stateProvince" ng-options="s.code for s in id.usStates"></select>
```

but it's not "linked" with the value in the backend data, i.e. it does not show "AL".  So, I assume I need to change my syntax somehow, but I am confused here...  the select docs are a bit confusing as well.

I created a simplified Plunker to show the situation: http://plnkr.co/edit/vvbbiiFprwNiTJTgWlR3?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am not wrong, and understood your question, you are looking for this solution.

Change your html to

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-init="selected=partner.partnerAddressInfo.stateProvince" ng-options="s.code as s.name for s in usStates"></select>
```

Let me know if i am right.

Comment: `selected=` i did not see that anywhere I've looked.  Many thanks.  I'm hoping the selected value gets "saved" back to the json for form submission?

Comment: in case of form submission use ng-submit(user) and user.selected so that data will be taken to the form. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for `ng-options` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

The "form" that you are currently using is the `label for value in arrray`

What you need is the `select as label for value in array` where `select` will bind the expression result to the model.
If you don't provide the `select` expression, then it will default to `value`

So, you need to change your syntax to -

```
<select ng-model="id.partner.partnerAddressInfo.stateProvince"
        ng-options="s.code for s.code for s in id.usStates">
</select>
```

Comment: That does not work.  I made a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vvbbiiFprwNiTJTgWlR3?p=preview